# Embedding video into UIWebView - Using link like 'http//qa.test.com/2323bjdsdd2232332'

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, html5-video

Its known that we could embed local media files inside webview and links such as from youtube (streamable).

But I am not sure, if we can link to urls like above. I tried with `<embed>, <video>, <iframe> and <object>`. Nothing worked for me.

> NSString *htmlString = `@"<html><head></head><body><video 
>   width="%0.0f" height="%0.0f" src="%@"></video></body></html>"`;

```
NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:url,self.webView.frame.size.width,self.webView.frame.size.height,self.htmlstr];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering with certain observation, correct me (this answer) if its wrong.

1. Local file or a link (itunes music or movies link) can be given to
   and played on UIWebView
2. Remote link (file) can be shown as well, but it has to streamable like youtube link. Just giving a link wont solve the problem it seems.